# Include wheelnav.js in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Im starting to learn Javascript and its various libraries and i want to test a circular navbar onto a wordpress site but the guides are confusing. They all talk about incorporating Jquery or the more famous libraries but not smaller ones like this wheelnav.js. Im assuming the process is the same right? I have the JS files downloaded but not sure where to upload them or if I need to enque them in somewhere? (PS I have read the codex but im still having a hard time making this sink in)

Answer (score 0):

You Try search the Codex (Docs).
 http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Created "js" folder inside theme templates folder and push your js file to "js" folder. Add this code to `<head>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src ="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>'/js/your_file_name.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enqueue wheelnav.js in your functions.php file along with it's dependency. You can follow [this blog post](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-scripts-and-styles-wordpress-enqueueing/).